# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Tags: php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
@mysql_select_db(WordPress_db);
?>
```

Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in D:\xampp\XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress_practice\db.php on line 2

Comment: what about:


`$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
@mysql_select_db($db);`

Comment: Be aware that the mysql_ extension was ***DEPRECATED*** in version 5.5 of PHP and was ***REMOVED*** from version 7.0 of PHP. You should now be using either the mysqli_ extension (note the i there) or PDO. When using any data that is being plugged into a query, having been sanitized/validated you should use prepared statements

Comment: <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db     = 'WordPress_db';
$conn  = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,'',$db);


if(! $conn){
  die('Could not connect connect: ') ;
}

echo 'Successfully Connected';


?>

Comment: It's not working whether I used mysqli_extention or mysql_extention 


Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in D:\xampp\XAMPP\htdocs\wordpress_practice\db.php on line 6
Could not connect connect: